# How to use custom word lists in Enchant?

Tags: php, enchant

I can't seem to get a personal word list working with Enchant.

I have a list of technical terms that I've been using happily with command line Hunspell for some time. It's just one word per line. The following code produces an empty array:

```
$b = enchant_broker_init();
$dict = enchant_broker_request_pwl_dict($b,'/path/to/my.pwl');
// enchant_dict_add($dict,'monospace'); // already in file
$suggestions = enchant_dict_suggest($dict,'monaspace');
```

Is this not how [enchant_broker_request_pwl_dict](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.enchant-broker-request-pwl-dict.php) is supposed to work?

Ideally I'd combine the built-in English dictionary with my custom list. I know I can add my words in memory using [enchant_dict_add_to_session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.enchant-dict-add-to-session.php) but I'd like to know what's wrong here.

I'm running this in PHP 8.0 on a Mac. The spelling backend appears to be aspell.

---

**Update 1**: I've established that use of [enchant_dict_check](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.enchant-dict-check.php) works with a PWL, and is case-insensitive as long as it's lower case in the file.

```
enchant_dict_check($dict,'Monospace'); // true
enchant_dict_check($dict,'monospace'); // true
```

Still, not much use if corrections to custom words can't be suggested. What is the recommended approach to this, using Enchant?

---

**Update 2**: I've now installed Enchant on my Linux server which uses Hunspell as the backend. Here `enchant_broker_request_pwl_dict` DOES work as per the code above, but `enchant_dict_add_to_session` does NOT. I'm still none the wiser how to merge the custom strings and base dictionary, other than by doing two spell checks for every word.

Comment: For the record, I've given up on Enchant and have Pspell working well instead. I dislike having different back ends on different OSes. Pspell always uses Aspell, and  Aspell's use of multiple/custom dictionaries is great.